# Which Schematron version does libxml2 implement?

Tags: libxml2, schematron

Libxml2 comes with a [Schematron module](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-schematron.html). Since [Schematron evolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron#Versions) quite a bit I am wondering what version the libxml2 implementation roughly matches.

Comment: Definitive answer would take more digging, but here's a start: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.lxml.devel/5057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [quick look at the source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/schematron.c), *libxml2* uses the namespace `http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron` which means ISO Schematron (2006). But there's a TODO comment saying

> divergences between the draft and the ISO proposed standard :-(

There don't seem to be any [changes to the source code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/log/schematron.c) that address this. So it's possible that *libxml2* only supports a draft version of the ISO standard (maybe Schematron 1.6?). I'd suggest to ask on the [*libxml2* mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/xml) to get a definite answer.